# GCP - Load balancing based on service availability

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

We have a service that can run with very fast latency but can't scale well and another service with low latency but can scale very well.
We would like to have a load balancer that will be able to transfer the traffic based on the availability of the different services. If the first service is able to get more requests then go to it, if not, go to the other service.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible @lee. You can customize to route your traffic based on your needs.

**Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing supports advanced traffic management functionality that enables you to use the following features:**

1. **Traffic steering:** Intelligently route traffic based on HTTP(S) parameters (for example, host, path, headers, and other request parameters).
2. **Traffic actions:** Perform request-based and response-based actions (for example, redirects and header transformations).
3. **Traffic policies:** Fine-tune load balancing behavior (for example, advanced load balancing algorithms).

Please refer these docs for addition information:

1. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/traffic-management
2. [https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing#:~:text=Distribute%20your%20load%2Dbalanced%20compute,or%20down%20with%20intelligent%20autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing#:%7E:text=Distribute%20your%20load%2Dbalanced%20compute,or%20down%20with%20intelligent%20autoscaling).
3. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview